Gradle build for JMeter repo fails with A problem occurred configuring project ':build-logic-commons:gradle-plugin'
I am trying to open the JMeter repo using IntelliJ IDEA, but getting some Gradle build errors.
I've tried creating a new project with Gradle as build system, and that works fine. Any ideas?
Very new to Gradle...appreciate if you can help with this! :)
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':build-logic-commons:gradle-plugin'.
> Failed to calculate the value of task ':build-logic-commons:gradle-plugin:compileJava' property 'javaCompiler'.
   > No matching toolchains found for requested specification: {languageVersion=17, vendor=any, implementation=vendor-specific} for LINUX on x86_64.
      > No locally installed toolchains match and toolchain download repositories have not been configured.

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Failed to query the value of property 'buildFlowServiceProperty'.
> Could not isolate value org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.statistics.BuildFlowService$Parameters_Decorated@5e8c6660 of type BuildFlowService.Parameters
   > A problem occurred configuring project ':build-logic-commons:gradle-plugin'.
      > Failed to calculate the value of task ':build-logic-commons:gradle-plugin:compileJava' property 'javaCompiler'.
         > No matching toolchains found for requested specification: {languageVersion=17, vendor=any, implementation=vendor-specific} for LINUX on x86_64.
            > No locally installed toolchains match and toolchain download repositories have not been configured.

